# Optimising mysql query - select inner join and exists

Tags: mysql

I have the following mysql query, the query takes a long time(4 secs) to execute. Is there any other way I could write it so that it takes quicker to execute. The dataset is fairly small (10 000 rows)

```
SELECT x.pid, x.rank, x.description, x.price, x.ifile 
FROM (SELECT product.pid, product.rank, product.description, product.price, images.ifile 
      FROM product INNER JOIN images ON product.pid=images.pid 
      WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM links WHERE product.pid=links.pid)
) as x 
WHERE x.description LIKE '%a%' 
ORDER BY x.rank ASC 
LIMIT 0,10
```

I have also tried the following with similar results:

```
SELECT product.pid, product.rank, product.description, product.price, images.ifile 
FROM product INNER JOIN images ON product.pid=images.pid 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM links WHERE product.pid=links.pid) 
  AND product.description LIKE '%a%' 
ORDER BY product.rank ASC 
LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: First identify the slowdown culprit - is it the `LIKE` in your where clause?

Comment: thanks good point. It seems to be WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM links WHERE product.pid=links.pid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correlated subqueries can be relatively expensive, instead of `EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM links WHERE product.pid=links.pid)` executing a query for every row from the outer query, it would probably be better to try `product.pid IN (SELECT pid FROM links)` or `product.pid IN (SELECT DISTINCT pid FROM links)`.

*If `links` were a **very** large table, and `product` relatively small, a correlated subquery could still be better.*

Comment: thanks it worked. Your second option product.pid IN (SELECT DISTINCT pid FROM links) got it down to 0.8 seconds

Answer (score 0):

It seems you already have your answer, but just curious, can you try this query?

```
select p.pid, p.rank, p.description, p.price, i.ifile 
  from product p
    inner join images i on i.pid = p.pid
    inner join links l on l.pid = p.pid
  where p.description like '%a%' 
  order by p.rank asc limit 0,10;
```

Comment: Thanks, it took longer - 2.07 seconds to execute. The other issue it joined the links table, I only needed to know if the link existed.

Comment: @the_big_blackbox a join could be faster than the query I provided in my answer, if `links.pid` is indexed, but must presume `pid` is unique in `links`.